# while restoring content in auto save module - An Ajax HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code : 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, drupal-7, autosave

When I edit my drupal node form, that get autosaved in 10 sec. While Again I want to restore my edited contents I got error :  An Ajax HTTP error occurred.  HTTP Result Code : 404 .

Debugging information as follows:

```
path: /testsite/autosave/restore/article-node-form/1404710992/7C7GQMqnDoadeuUvzhmk_4iWh8P4hgAcosf9ekAvRaIc/seven
StatusText: Not Found
ResponseText: 
404 Not Found
Not Found
The requested URL /testsite/autosave/restore/article-node-form/1404710992/7C7GQMqnDoadeUvzhmk_4iWh8P4hgAcosf9ekAvRaIc/seven was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

in the browser console I'm getting log message:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Service unavailable (with message))**

and path is given below that:

**/testsite/autosave/restore/article-node-form/1404710992/7C7GQMqnDoadeuUvzhmk_4iWh8P4hgAcosf9ekAvRaIc/seven**

Answer (score 0):

The **500** message might be seen in any number of ways because each website is allowed to customize the message.

and as you have told that the node is autosaved in 10 sec...and you are getting this message while again restoring yours edited content.

So i think this might be a case of nested iterations of autosave and restoring the same entity. You should debug your node on submit.